# Why is the kinetic helicity of a fluid important?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, topology, fluid-statics, vortex

In fluid dynamics, the kinetic helicity is a measure of the degree of knottedness and/or linkage of the vortex lines of the flow.

- It's a conserved and topological quantity.
- It has no effect on the equations of motion.

Thus my *naive* question: **Why then is the kinetic helicity important if it has no influence on the equations of motion?**

Sure, if we are interested in how many knots there are, the kinetic helicity tells us that. However, what more can we learn from the kinetic helicity? In what regard is a system with large kinetic helicity different from a system with small kinetic helicity? My suspicion is that kinetic helicity is in a sense a measure of turbulence of the fluid. Formulated differently: maybe the kinetic helicity can be used to classify different phases of a given fluid system?!

Comment: Or may be people just publish whatever they _can_ publish.